# While limiting input length of text box by maxlength property, how to explicitly handle the event that the max length has been exceeded?

Tags: html, textbox, maxlength

My purpose is to limit the user input (which is free text) inside a simple HTML text box to 5 characters. I am using the input field's **maxlength** property to ensure that, **but I need to display a popup** when the user tries to type more than 5 characters.

I tried to handle **keydown** events, but then an ugly if-else would have to be put in order to not take into consideration del,enter,F1..F12, Alt,Page Dn, etc...as all these are allowed, but they don't contribute to the text's length Their keycodes are also not in one sequence. I tried to handle it on **keyup**, but the character is already typed by that time, and the user sees the extra character disappearing.. not something I want.

A pre-HTML5 solution.. something that would work on IE7,8 would be very useful.

Comment: What about `onchange` event? And then checking wheter value has more then `n` characters?

Comment: no.. onchange fires only after the element loses focus...i want the popup displayed as soon as he types the extra character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gecko (e.g. firefox) the browser prevents that the value becomes longer if you use the `maxlength` attribute, so the `tooLong` validation variable will ever be `false` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/ValidityState)). There is no chance to hook there.
But you can use the `pattern`-attribute instead:

```
<input ... pattern="^.{0,max}$" />
```

Replace `max` in the `pattern` regex with the number of maximum allowed characters.
Now you can bind the `input`-event and check the boolean `element.validity.patternMismatch` if the value is to long.

Here are links to two examples I've created for you; they are tested with the current versions of firefox and chrome, I can't test with IE9:

- [first example](http://jsfiddle.net/S4Sq4/): if the value is to long, it will be cut and for one second an error message will be shown; a small disadvantage is that you can see the input in a fraction of a second.
- in the [second example](http://jsfiddle.net/cPXCc/) the value will never be changed, an error message will be shown until the number of characters is correct and you can only submit the form if all fields are valid.

=== UPDATE ===

For IE7 and IE8 support I have updated the examples:

- [example1](http://jsfiddle.net/S4Sq4/3/)
- [example2](http://jsfiddle.net/cPXCc/11/)

Comment: From a usability standpoint, I think the second example is much better. People can be easily confused, and having the input value *not* change when they type something (via maxlength in this case) can be annoying and makes it harder to correct the mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot..but I need to test this on IE7,8 also.... plus, with browsers that don't support the 'pattern' attribute on input elements or any HTML5 introductions. Sry, I didn't mention it before... Am editing the question now

Comment: Thanks again..the first example in both the cases is relevant to me.. but as I said in my question and you pointed out yourself that the disadvantage of handling the keyup event is that the typed character is visible for a fraction of time before disappearing.. this is what I want to prevent... Also, as I said in the question, I want to limit him to the maximum number of characters..I can't allow him to continue typing after he reached the maximum limit.